# Issue with left recursion in top down parsing

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, grammar

I have read [this](http://qntm.org/top) to understand more the difference between top down and bottom up parsing, can anyone explain the problems associated with left recursion in a top down parser?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a top-down parser, the parser begins with the start symbol and tries to guess which productions to apply to reach the input string. To do so, top-down parsers need to use contextual clues from the input string to guide its guesswork.

Most top-down parsers are directional parsers, which scan the input in some direction (typically, left to right) when trying to determine which productions to guess. The LL(k) family of parsers is one example of this - these parsers use information about the next k symbols of input to determine which productions to use.

Typically, the parser uses the next few tokens of input to guess productions by looking at which productions can ultimately lead to strings that start with the upcoming tokens. For example, if you had the production

> A → bC

you wouldn't choose to use this production unless the next character to match was b. Otherwise, you'd be guaranteed there was a mismatch. Similarly, if the next input character was b, you might want to choose this production.

So where does left recursion come in? Well, suppose that you have these two productions:

> A → Ab | b

This grammar generates all strings of one or more copies of the character b. If you see a b in the input as your next character, which production should you pick? If you choose Ab, then you're assuming there are multiple b's ahead of you even though you're not sure this is the case. If you choose b, you're assuming there's only one b ahead of you, which might be wrong. In other words, if you have to pick one of the two productions, you can't always choose correctly.

The issue with left recursion is that if you have a nonterminal that's left-recursive and find a string that might match it, you can't necessarily know whether to use the recursion to generate a longer string or avoid the recursion and generate a shorter string. Most top-down parsers will either fail to work for this reason (they'll report that there's some uncertainty about how to proceed and refuse to parse), or they'll potentially use extra memory to track each possible branch, running out of space.

In short, top-down parsers usually try to guess what to do from limited information about the string. Because of this, they get confused by left recursion because they can't always accurately predict which productions to use.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Reasons

1)The grammar which are left recursive(Direct/Indirect) can't be converted into {Greibach normal form (GNF)}* So the Left recursion can be eliminated to Right Recuraive Format.

2)Left Recursive Grammars are also nit LL(1),So again elimination of left Recursion may result into LL(1) grammer.

*GNF
 A Grammer of the form A->aV* is Greibach Normal Form.